# how to execute two exe files at the same time in delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have two exe files and I want to run them at the same time.  Is it possible to do it in delphi 7?  I've searched it in the internet but I couldn't find any answer...

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What does "run them at the same time" mean? Do you mean "start them at the same exact moment"? Or do you mean "run one, and then the other"?

Answer (score 2):

Iman said in a comment:

> NO, I run two exe files, the first one take some files and produce an output for each file. the second exe run at the same time and wait for output of the first one, so when the first exe file is working on second input the second exe is working on first output of first exe :) something like pipeline

What I would do then, is start the 2nd program first. It will then be ready for the output of the first one as soon as the output is produced and there will be no delay.

Answer (score 1):

Just execute one, and then the other.  It's very difficult to make computers do anything at exactly the same time, a millisecond apart shouldn't kill you.

Comment: dear @wug this is more than a millisecond, one of them produce a file and another one manipulates it and it repeats for about 300 files. but Anyway thanks for answer.

Comment: Are you saying that what you actually want to do is run one, then wait for it to finish, and THEN run the other?

Comment: NO, I run two exe files, the first one take some files and produce an output for each file. the second exe run at the same time and wait for output of the first one, so when the first exe file is working on second input the second exe is working on first output of first exe :) something like pipeline...

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't just run the first, then wait for it to finish, then run the second

Comment: Since the second exe waits for the file to be produced, there is no reason not to just run them at the same time without having your own app waiting on the first exe. Especially if the first exe produces multiple files, then you can't have your app do any waiting anyway.  Just call `ShellExecute()` or `CreateProcess()` to start the first exe, and then call it again to start the second exe.